# MongoDB: Query using $gte and $lte in java

Tags: java, mongodb, querying

I want to perform a query on a field that is greater than or equal to, AND less than or equal to(I'm using java btw). In other words. >= and <=. As I understand, mongoDB has $gte and $lte operators, but I can't find the proper syntax to use it. The field i'm accessing is a top-level field.

I have managed to get this to work:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("1dag").find(new Document("timestamp", new Document("$gt", 1412204098)));
```

as well ass...

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("1dag").find(new Document("timestamp", new Document("$lt", 1412204098)));
```

But how do you combine these with each other?

Currently I'm playing around with a statement like this, but it does not work:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable5 = db.getCollection("1dag").find(new Document( "timestamp", new Document("$gte", 1412204098).append("timestamp", new Document("$lte",1412204099))));
```

Any help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically you require a range query like this:

```
db.getCollection("1dag").find({
    "timestamp": {
        "$gte": 1412204098,
        "$lte": 1412204099
    }
})
```

Since you need multiple query conditions for this range query, you can can specify a logical conjunction (AND) by appending conditions to the query document using the **[`append()`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/org/bson/Document.html?&_ga=1.219073369.1902957641.1421252340#append-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)** method:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("1dag").find(
        new Document("timestamp", new Document("$gte", 1412204098).append("$lte", 1412204099)));
```

Answer (score 3):

The constructor `new Document(key, value)` only gets you a document with one key-value pair. But in this case you need to create a document with more than one. To do this, create an empty document, and then add pairs to it with `.append(key, value)`.

```
Document timespan = new Document();
timespan.append("$gt", 1412204098);
timespan.append("$lt", 1412204998);
// timespan in JSON: 
// { $gt: 1412204098, $lt: 1412204998}
Document condition = new Document("timestamp", timespan);
// condition in JSON:
// { timestamp: { $gt: 1412204098, $lt: 1412204998} }

FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("1dag").find(condition);
```

Or if you really want to do it with a one-liner without temporary variables:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("1dag").find(
    new Document()
        .append("timestamp", new Document()
             .append("$gt",1412204098)
             .append("$lt",1412204998)
        )
);
```

Comment: Your one-liner had syntax errors, but your solution works. Although the run-time was slower than the accepted answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @kongshem Can you please suggest an edit to fix those syntax errors?

Comment: I'm on it, but it seems like the operator ":" is causing the trouble. Or perhaps the creation of empty documents using the .append function.

Comment: Indeed it was the ":" operator. Using "," solved it. The run-time for my data collection is still half a second slower. (700MB of test data, I'm going to use it on up to 1TB). I'll edit your response.